# Android app using GLES20 Textureview keeps needing buffer memory till crash

Tags: android, textureview

I have an app that uses BLE and controls devices, also on the same activity I am using a TextureView that implements Surfaceview so there is 3D interactivity in a window on the same activity.  It all works fine, but after a few minutes the app crashes.  investigation shows that the memory usage keeps increasing, as if the app is accumulating buffers during the rendering.

It is a complex app and too much to post here, but I would appreciate contact with someone who might assist.  We can post results on here once the issue is located.

The memory issue is isolated to the textureview implementation, my guess is the continual redraw is allocating lots of buffers and never releasing.

Comment: Use a heap analysis tool like MAT to determine where the memory is going. TextureView does not accumulate buffers without bound.

Comment: Thanks.  I read your contributions on Android Graphics architecture, and followed this to systrace using Android Device Monitor (Android Studio).  It is not buffers as I can see.  At this stage I am at a loss.  Any further suggestions?